# CssSyntaxError Unknown Word when building with webpack but dev server is running perfectly

Tags: vue.js, webpack, postcss, webpack-style-loader, postcss-loader

I'm New To Vue and Webpack
The project is running on my development server, works well when i run

```
npm run dev
```

But When i run

```
npm run build
```

The Following Error is generating

```
     Error processing file: static/css

/app.81fa529b08a5e9b00d3a8b61096d58b1.css
(node:8608) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CssSyntaxError: I:\projects\Vue\getit\static\css\app.81fa529b08a5e9b00d3a8b61096d58b1.css:104:21: Unknown word
    at Input.error (I:\projects\Vue\getit\node_modules\optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:130:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (I:\projects\Vue\getit\node_modules\optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:563:22)
    at Parser.decl (I:\projects\Vue\getit\node_modules\optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:235:16)
    at Parser.other (I:\projects\Vue\getit\node_modules\optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:133:18)
    at Parser.parse (I:\projects\Vue\getit\node_modules\optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:77:16)
    at parse (I:\projects\Vue\getit\node_modules\optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:17:12)
    at new LazyResult (I:\projects\Vue\getit\node_modules\optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:60:16)
    at Processor.<anonymous> (I:\projects\Vue\getit\node_modules\optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:138:12)
    at Processor.process (I:\projects\Vue\getit\node_modules\optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:117:23)
    at Function.creator.process (I:\projects\Vue\getit\node_modules\optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin\node_modules\postcss\lib\postcss.js:148:43)
    at OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin.processCss (I:\projects\Vue\getit\node_modules\optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin\index.js:63:19)
    at Object.processor (I:\projects\Vue\getit\node_modules\optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin\index.js:29:23)
    at I:\projects\Vue\getit\node_modules\last-call-webpack-plugin\index.js:139:8
    at arrayEach (I:\projects\Vue\getit\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (I:\projects\Vue\getit\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at LastCallWebpackPlugin.process (I:\projects\Vue\getit\node_modules\last-call-webpack-plugin\index.js:136:3)
(node:8608) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:8608) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Do you have some code which you think could be related to the error messages?

Comment: Thanks @Simson for your interest  So i just solved it , I inserted some html code in css